# Rendering Images to the most simple react web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]so I am studying react and trying to map and render pictures from an array of objects from a separate JS file.
The problem is that what renders(screenshot) is broken and I can't seem to find a fix for it.
**Please disregard** a Count function on the screen, I merely practice the functionality and understand that I should divide the labor of components and keep it simple and true to a single task, but for now, I included it.
The images are stored within src folder in a separate folder called 'images'

```
import { arrayForList } from "./arrayForList";

//This is my renderImage function to the screen
function Image({ src, name }) {
   return <img src={src} alt={name} />;
 }
 
 function ImageList({ images }) {
   return (
     <div>
       {images.map((image) => (
         <Image key={image.id} src={image.src} name={image.name} />
       ))}
     </div>
   );
 }
 
 
 export function Appl() {
   return <ImageList images={arrayForList} />;
 }
```

---

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Appl} from './ImageRenderFunction';


//This is the counter(unrelated) and image render within that Counter.

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const handleDecrement = () => {
    setCount(count - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Counter: {count}</h2>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={handleDecrement}>Decrement</button>
      <Appl />
    </div>

  );
}

export  default Counter;
```

```
import pizzaImg from './images/Pizza-thick.png';


export const arrayForList = [
    {   name: "Pizza",
        src: pizzaImg,
        id: 1,
        price: 5,
     },
     {  name: "Burger",
        src: '/images/Burger.png', 
        id: 2,
        price: 5,
     },
     {  name: "Momo",
        src: '/images/Momo-food.png',
        id: 3,
        price: 5,
     },
     {  name: "Hotdog",
        src: '/images/Hotdog.png',
        id: 4,
        price: 5,
     },
     {  name: "Chicken-Burger",
        src: '/images/Chicken-Burger.png',
        id: 5,
        price: 5,
     },
     {  name: "Chicken-Pizza",
        src: '/images/Pizza-thick.png',
        id: 6,
        price: 5,
     },
     {  name: "Dominos",
        src: '/images/Pizza-thick.png',
        id: 7,
        price: 5,
     },
     {  name: "McDonald Special", 
        src: '/images/Set-of-food.jpeg',
        id: 8,
        price: 5,
     }
]
```

Comment: Have a look with the developer tools of the browser, where is *actually* pointing the `src` parameter of the images? Most likely, those addresses are wrong.

Comment: Hey there, so I went through a bit of searching and found out that the problem is that I use relative paths, instead of absolute. 
I tried absoulte and it worked, however now I am puzzled what to do when you have 50 pictures you need to render?
It cannot be that you would import all of them separately and then insert them. 
I am working with an array of objects where links to the images are stored.
I will include what array I have now, please let me know what I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
src={`${URL.createObjectURL(image?.src)}`}
```

or,

```
src={`${rootUrl}${image?.src}`}
```

Here, rootUrl looks like "192.168.31.183:8000".